# How can I move the Main Camera to a new position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayingInGameScenesController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LockController lockController;
    public Vector3 targetPosition;
    public GameObject uiTextsImage;
    public float cameraMoveSpeed;

    private bool newGame = true;
    private bool playingScene = true;

    public void PlayingSceneInGame()
    {
        PlayingSceneStatesControls(true);
        StartCoroutine(ScenePlayingTime());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != "Main Menu" && newGame == true)
        {
            PlayingSceneInGame();
            newGame = false;
        }

        if(playingScene == false)
        {
            // X 40.73769 to -6     Y 1.1 to 1     Z -4.641718 to 43.4
            Vector3 camPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
            Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(camPos.x)
            Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Camera.main.transform.position, targetPosition, cameraMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void PlayingSceneStatesControls(bool LockState)
    {
        lockController.LockControl(LockState);

        if (LockState == true)
        {
            // change state of free look camera height and view distance.
            // change the cameras states enable true/false.
            // change the ui texts for description text and scene text enable true/false.

            uiTextsImage.SetActive(true);

        }
        else
        {
            uiTextsImage.SetActive(false);
            playingScene = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ScenePlayingTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);

        PlayingSceneStatesControls(false);
    }
}
```

In the Update :

```
if(playingScene == false)
        {
            // X 40.73769 to -6     Y 1.1 to 1     Z -4.641718 to 43.4
            Vector3 camPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
            Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(camPos.x)
            Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Camera.main.transform.position, targetPosition, cameraMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
```

First should I move the two variables camPos and newPos to the Start ?
Second the values X Y Z the left values is where the camera is position at now and the right values where to should move to smooth slowly. From the current position on X the current position is 40.73769 to -6 same for the Y and Z I just wrote this values to remember but the idea is to move smooth slowly the camera from the current position to the new position : X -6 Y 1 and Z to 43.4

Should I do it in the Update or Late or Fixed Update ?

This is the main camera original position :

[image: Main Camera original position]

And this is the target position I want the main camera to get I entered the new target position values :

[image: The position that should be the target of the main camera]

What I tried :

In the Start :

```
private void Start()
    {
        Vector3 camPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
        newPos = new Vector3(camPos.x - 46.73769f, camPos.y - 0.1f, camPos.z + 48.041718f);
    }
```

Then in the Update :

```
if(playingScene == false)
        {
            // X 40.73769 - 46.73769     Y 1.1 - 0.1     Z -4.641718 + 48.041718
            Camera.main.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Camera.main.transform.position, newPos, cameraMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
```

Then I changed the values in the Start switched Z and X :

```
private void Start()
    {
        Vector3 camPos = Camera.main.transform.position;
        newPos = new Vector3(camPos.x - 48.041718f, camPos.y - 0.1f, camPos.z + 46.73769f);
    }
```

In both cases the main camera start from some other position not the original position at all and ending in other position :

Starting somewhere under/inside the spaceship :

[image: Original position is inside the spaceship not the camera original position]

And ending here :

[image: Ending in this position]

Answer (score 0):

Working :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayingInGameScenesController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject camera;
    public LockController lockController;
    public GameObject uiTextsImage;
    public float transitionSpeed = 5f;
    public Transform currentView;

    // The initial offset from the target.
    private Vector3 offset;
    private bool newGame = true;
    private bool playingScene = true;
    private Vector3 newPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        currentView.position = new Vector3(43.4f, 1f,-6f);
        offset = camera.transform.position - currentView.position;
    }

    public void PlayingSceneInGame()
    {
        PlayingSceneStatesControls(true);
        StartCoroutine(ScenePlayingTime());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name != "Main Menu" && newGame == true)
        {
            PlayingSceneInGame();
            newGame = false;
        }
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (playingScene == false)
        {
            //Lerp position
            camera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(camera.transform.position, currentView.position, Time.deltaTime * transitionSpeed);
        }
    }

    private void PlayingSceneStatesControls(bool LockState)
    {
        lockController.LockControl(LockState);

        if (LockState == true)
        {
            // change state of free look camera height and view distance.
            // change the cameras states enable true/false.
            // change the ui texts for description text and scene text enable true/false.

            uiTextsImage.SetActive(true);

        }
        else
        {
            uiTextsImage.SetActive(false);
            playingScene = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ScenePlayingTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);

        PlayingSceneStatesControls(false);
    }
}
```